# PHP gettext() in Norwegian

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I'm using PHP's `gettext()` for simply transform a website to an other language. The solution worked fine (English/Hungarian) until now because i need to add a Norwegian translation to a new site.

When i set the Norwegian locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "nb_NO.ISO8859-1");` `gettext()` only returns the base string not the translated one.

Is this related with my operating systems' installed locales (`en_US.UTF-8, hu_HU.UTF-8`) so i need to add the Norwegian one too or something else causing this?

Thanks for your help,
fabrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IIRC, you need to have locale on the system to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I was confused because i didn't want to add another locale to my system without real reason. As i added it works like a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: How do you add locales on Windows?

Comment: @Svish, sorry, no slightest idea on windows.