# How to add Norwegian to setlocale()?

Tags: php, setlocale

I want to add Norwegian date. So that I can have two languages on my website.

According to PHP manual, it says that

> The return value of setlocale()
>   depends on the system that PHP is
>   running. It returns exactly what the
>   system setlocale function returns.

How can I add Norwegian ?

Thanks in advance.

I want to use setlocale(), and strftime() as followings. (for Norwegian and English)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");
echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A,");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %A and");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
echo strftime(" in German %A.\n");
```

Comment: Please take a look at my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431354/php-gettext-in-norwegian hope it helps.

Comment: If you ask me, `setlocale()` sucks ass. I am a friend of managing this manually or using a library like [`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en//zend.locale.html)so you don't have to depend on locales being installed on the server (and sometimes still not working)

Answer (score 7):

You would need to install the Norwegian locale, if it isn't installed yet. How to do that, depends on your server OS.

If the examples you show work already, and/or it's a norwegian server, chances are it is already installed. I would try whether one of `no_NO`, `no_NN` (Nynorsk) and `no_NB` (Bokmål) does the trick.

On a side note though, the very fact that these functions rely so heavily on the underlying OS's setup, and the way to address the language codes/locales varies from system to system (thus adding utter chaos to the program's configuration!), have convinced me that using a PHP-based library like [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) for this  is the much better option.

I'm not sure how well norwegian is supported by it out of the box, but I'm pretty sure adding the necessary resources is easy.

Comment: at least in Ubuntu 20.04 it's called `nb_NO`  and `nn_NO` , you got the names in reverse (: