# Zend Framework 2.3 Translation ignoring manual setLocale() - Possible gettext issue

Tags: php, localization, zend-framework2, gettext

I'm new to ZF2, and have tried setting up a locale switcher. The code seems to work, but no matter how I've tried, I can't get the switch to happen. I have localised DB calls, which all work fine, but the default gettext/Zend Translate never changes from the default locale.

My code is as follows:

module.config.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'website' => 'o',

    'accepted_locales' => array(
        'en_GB' => array(
            'country'      => 'gb',
            'language'     => 'en',
            'display_name' => 'English',
        ),

        'no_NO' => array(
            'country'      => 'no',
            'language'     => 'no',
            'display_name' => 'Norsk',
        ),
    ),

    'default_locale' => 'en_GB',

    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Foo\Controller\Bar' => 'Foo\Controller\BarController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'oranisation' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller][/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Foo\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Bar',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'translator' => array(
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Organisation' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            [...]
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Custom Abstract Controller - method called for all actions on all controllers in the project

```
/**
 * Determines most appropriate locale by checking browser locale, then using a default if
 * browser is unsupported.
 *
 * @return String
 */
protected function getBestLocale()
{
    $locales    = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['accepted_locales'];

    if ( isset($_GET['locale']) && in_array($_GET['locale'], array_keys($locales)) ) {

        // If locale has been set manually, and is valid, configure the translator
        $locale = $_GET['locale'];

    } else {

        if ( in_array($this->getRequest()->getCookie()->locale, array_keys($locales)) ) {

            // If the locale is already set, ensure it's valid, and confirm the current locale
            $locale = $this->getRequest()->getCookie()->locale;

        } elseif ( in_array(locale_accept_from_http($this->getRequest()->getHeader()), array_keys($locales)) ) {

            // If still not set, we will set from the client header
            $locale = locale_accept_from_http($this->getRequest()->getHeader());

        } else {

            // Default
            $locale = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['default_locale'];

        }
    }

    $cookie = new SetCookie('locale', $locale, time()+60*60*24*30, null, 'localhost');
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

    Locale::setDefault($locale);

    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Translator')->setLocale($locale);

    return $locale;
}
```

I have translation files (.po/.mo set up for en_GB and no_NO) and I'm calling the following in my views:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('File list'); ?>
```

I ALWAYS get the untranslated strings.

There seem to be various ways of implementing this, and the variety is quite confusing - so to be specific, I'm using ZF 2.3.0. What am I missing please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz , check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513140/zf2-translation/22529343#22529343 . answers of this question may help you

Comment: Thanks @admin_arab, but it does not do anything for me at all. Still the same result. I'm considering that it can't find the translations for some reason, as that's the one setting I can freely change with no error reporting at all, although I still don't understand why this would be, my paths are definitely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's a bit of a hack, but I got it working - the translator didn't seem to be populating correctly, so `$this->translate('...')` wasn't using the translate object I was configuring for some reason, and by adding the lines:

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$view->setVariable('translator', $translator);
```

I can now use:

```
<?php echo $this->translator->translate('...'); ?>
```

Which has the desired effect. If anybody has a good way of re-attaching these `translator` variables, I'd still appreciate it, because this still seems like an extremely hack-ish solution.

Comment: OK, it was that there were two translators - This was the second module running on the same project. The base module for all other modules in the project contained the code for another translation element in the `module.config.php`. Once I deleted that, no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Zend supported locales list : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.appendix.html

Zend not support no_NO . May be better use nn_NO or nb_NO or something else .

Comment: He's using ZF2 not ZF1, so ZF1 doc are a no-no here.

Comment: Zend use php Local class and check this URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922368/how-to-add-norwegian-to-setlocale

Comment: Good spot, but I've replaced with these, and am checking the locale from ZF2, which is coming back correctly as "no" or "nn_NO", and _still_ not translating anything.

Comment: I've also tried setting this using `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Translator')->setLocale($locale)`, and `Locale::setDefault($locale);` but neither seems to work. The locale returned if I query `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Translator')->getLocale()` is the correct 'no' or 'en_GB' appropriately, but the `$this->translate('Foo');` will always return 'Foo' no matter what. I really am more convinced it's a problem with gettext - and again, I've checked my paths, etc.