# Can't get gettext (php) on Ubuntu working

Tags: php, ubuntu, gettext, php-gettext

The following example works on Mac OS X with Apache, i.e. I get the translated string echoed back. But on Ubuntu with lighttpd I get the original text 'Inactive account'. I've tried all sorts of combinations of environment varialbes without any luck. It's not file permissions either because I can echo out the contents of the .mo file.

```
<?php

//$locale = 'sv_SE.UTF-8';
$locale = 'sv_SE';

$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

// File permission is apparantly not a problem as this works...
//echo file_get_contents($dir . '/sv_SE/LC_MESSAGES/flattr.mo');

putenv("LANG=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
//setlocale(LANG, $locale);
//setlocale(LANGUAGE, $locale);

bindtextdomain('flattr', $dir);
//bind_textdomain_codeset("flattr", 'UTF-8');
textdomain('flattr');

echo _("Inactive account");

?>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Has the language properly set up in the OS itself? See my previous question maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431354/php-gettext-in-norwegian

Comment: Have you generated the locale for sv_SE ? If not, then add (or uncomment) a line containing `sv_SE.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.gen` and then run `sudo locale-gen`.

Comment: sudo locale-gen sv_SE.UTF-8 (and then restart lighttpd) worked. Could you post it as an answer to this question so I can mark it as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. I'll describe the things I did to fix it on Ubuntu 10.10.

1) make sure you have 'gettext' installed,

```
sudo apt-get install gettext
```

Alternatively, you can install 'php-gettext' if 'gettext' cannot be installed. The package 'php-gettext' is not required if you already have 'gettext' installed.

2) Then generate the locale for your language. In this example I'll use 'sv_SE'. Look up the supported locales in '/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED',

```
less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

You'll find multiple lines that start with 'sv_SE',

```
sv_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8
sv_SE ISO-8859-1
sv_SE.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
```

This means you have multiple options for generating the locale for sv_SE. One of the options does not have a period (.) in its name (i.e. `sv_SE ISO-8859-1`); this is the default character set for that locale. To generate the locale for the default character set, run the following command,

```
sudo locale-gen sv_SE
```

If you want to generate that locale for the UTF-8 character set, run this command,

```
sudo locale-gen sv_SE.UTF-8
```

Restart Apache after generating locales (it won't find the newly generated locales otherwise),

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

3) Finally, update your PHP script to match the locale you generated. If you generated the locale for 'sv_SE',

> setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE");

But if you generated the UTF-8 equivalent of that locale, use,

> setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");

All should work now.

Comment: On Debian turns out there is a package called `locales-all` which may provide an easier way out without having to do `locale-gen` manually. I also needed to `apt-get install locales`

Answer (score 1):

Though I followed the steps outlined in the accepted answer, I couldn't get it to work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I had to do two important things:

(1) Before generating the messages.mo file, I had to specify in message.po explicitly UTF-8 for charset:

```
msgid   ""
msgstr  "Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
        "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
        "POT-Creation-Date: 2016-12-19 16:28+0530\n"
        "PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
        "Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
        "Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
        "Language: \n"
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"    <---------change here
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
```

(2) I had to maintain same folder name as the locale installed.  For instance, I installed Kannada by running `sudo locale-gen kn_IN`.  This generated `kn_IN.UTF-8`.  Note the capital letters and hyphen in UTF-8.  I used this same name while setting locale in my php script and for the folder name where I put the messages.mo file:

PHP Script:

```
// I18N support information
$locale = "kn_IN.UTF-8";       <----------change here
putenv("LANG=".$locale); 
putenv("LC_ALL=".$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);
```

Folder Name:

```
project_folder
    /Locale
        /kn_IN.UTF-8      <------change here
            /LC_MESSAGES
                /messages.mo
```

Ubuntu is case sensitive to folder and file names.  So make sure the capital letters are maintained as shown above.