# php startup error gettext library not found

Tags: php

i get this error on a page on load:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But i checked phpinfo and Gettext support is enabled
Also i've already installed gettext and php-gettext, but gettext.so does not exists on that path!
I'm PHP Version 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.4

Comment: did you check the file exists

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6087538/3558278

Comment: @Dagon The file does not exists

Comment: @Deep I tried this solution but i still get the problem

Comment: well then the error is clear?

Comment: @Dagon Yes it is, but why? and How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to comment extension in apache2/php.ini:

```
;extension=gettext.so
```